# Accumulate in PostgreSQL with ltree column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I ran into a problem with the ltree data type column in PostgreSQL as follows.

This is the `Asset` table:

| Id | Name | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ass1 | 1 |
| 2 | Ass2 | 1 |
| 3 | Ass3 | 2 |
| 4 | Ass4 | 3 |
| 5 | Ass5 | 4 |
| 6 | Ass6 | 4 |
| 7 | Ass7 | 4 |

This is the `AssetGroup` table:

| Id | Name | Path | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | grp1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | grp2 | 1.2 | 2 |
| 3 | grp3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | grp4 | 3.4 | 2 |

I want to create a query statement to count the number of Assets that each group has and expect that the result of the number of Assets of the parent group is the total number of Assets it has for itself and its child records.

The expected result should be:

| Id | Name | Path | Level | AssetQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | grp1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | grp2 | 1.2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | grp3 | 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | grp4 | 3.4 | 2 | 3 |

My maintenance query is:

```
SELECT grp_parent."Id"
    , grp_parent."Name"
    , grp_parent."Path"
    , grp_parent."Level"
    , COUNT("Asset".*) AS "AssetQuantity"
FROM "AssetGroup" grp_parent
LEFT JOIN "AssetGroup" grp_child
ON (
    grp_parent."Path" @> grp_Child."Path"
    AND grp_child."DelFlag" = FALSE
)
JOIN "Asset" ON (
    grp_child."Id" = "Asset"."GroupId"
    AND "Asset"."DelFlag" = FALSE
)
GROUP BY grp_parent."Path"
, grp_parent."Id"
```

However, the result for now is:

| Id | Name | Path | Level | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | grp1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | grp2 | 1.2 | 2 | 1 |

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive `cte`:

```sql
with recursive cte as (
   select g.id, g.name, g.path, g.level, g.level level1, g.id id1, g.path p1 
   from assetgroup g
   union all
   select c.id, c.name, c.path, c.level, g1.level level1, g1.id id1, g1.path p1 from cte c 
   join assetgroup g1 on g1.path ~ ('^'||c.path) 
   where c.level1 < g1.level
)
select c.id, c.name, c.path, c.level, sum(case when a.groupid is null then 0 else 1 end) c from cte c 
left join asset a on a.groupid = c.id1
group by c.id, c.name, c.path, c.level
order by c.id
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NP4yZSyZ)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The query was able to find most of the parent-child pairs. However, it doesn't work in case where there are only parent records without child records. Is there any way to handle this case?
I also made some changes in your query due to the fact that I can use the "<@" operator in ltree.

```sql
...
   join assetgroup g1 on g1.path <@ c.path 
```

Comment: @NguyenQuocBao I have updated the solution to reflect this. The fiddle's `assetgroup` now includes a row representing a group with no child records in `asset`.

Comment: Thank you. Although I notice that the query in fiddle now returns the value of column c representing the value of the number of assets in grp5 which is wrong (it should return the value 0 because there are no records of the asset table with groupId is 5 - Id of grp5) However, I think I can figure it out and handle it myself from here.

Comment: @NguyenQuocBao Please see my recent edit.